# Passwords and svn

Tags: security, svn, ssh

Hi I am accessing a repository through a URL of type svn+ssh://
Reading the following quote from [SVN and SSH from Adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/406/kb406167.html) I am a little confused

"Before you configure Subversion or Dreamweaver for SVN+SSH, create an RSA key pair and configure the public key on the server. This public/private key pair is used to authenticate with the server, instead of storing and passing your password in plain text."

So if I just acces a repository by svn+ssh:// pe. from command line, my password is send in clear text ? I thought part of ssh was to encrypt the password, no ?

Maybe I was unclear, I have not generated any keypairs so use my password every time, does that change anything or is the quote written in confusing way ? Thank you.

Comment: You missed the next part of the quote: *(It is possible to configure SSH without using key pairs; however, Adobe doesn't recommend doing so because of the lack of security.)* So it's just a recommendation.

Comment: Ok. So what lack of security is the reference to ? I read it as if they were saying : No key-pair => passsword sent in clear text,

Comment: SSH never sends passwords in plain text. However, non-SSH protocols such as `svn://` may send the password in plain text. Adobe is recommending that users use SSH. Adobe also recommends that if SSH is used, then RSA key pairs are also used. Key pairs are easier because you don't have to keep typing your password for every operation (when used with an SSH agent).

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand. This super comment is a complete answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Part of ssh is to encrypt *everything*, not just your password.  So, your password would not be going over the wire in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

SSH never sends passwords in plain text. However, non-SSH protocols such as svn:// may send the password in plain text. Adobe is recommending that users use SSH. Adobe also recommends that if SSH is used, then RSA key pairs are also used. Key pairs are easier because you don't have to keep typing your password for every operation (when used with an SSH agent).

Answer (score 0):

There is no password at all in this case. All authentication happens based on key pair. One key is on your client machine, another one lies on the server. All traffic is also encrypted.